# MYSQL Followers System: Indexing the Followers Table

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I am working on an app that incorporates following just like Twitter & Instagram. I have a question regarding indexing the followers table. Take my two MYSQL tables for ex.

```
users
- user_id
- username
...

followers 
- id
- user_id
- follower_id
...
index(user_id,follower_id)
```

I have been reading about indexes here: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really.
From my understanding the indexes are sorted by leftmost column in the index specified. So in this case, it's user_id and follower_id is scattered all throughout the table?

```
*followers Table
id    user_id    follower_id
————————————————————--------
1        5          6
2        5          8
3        5          11
4        7          6
```

So if i run the simple query below it should be efficient and allow me to retrieve the people who x user follows:

```
SELECT * FROM followers WHERE user_id=5
```

However, what happens if i need to get the people who follow someone? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follower_id = 6
```

From my understanding, follower_id would only be sorted in order after the user_id column. Therefore, it occurs all throughout the table and the whole table must be checked?

What is the best way to handle this and what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

From your example, this point stands out:

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> To find the rows matching a WHERE clause quickly.

I would index both `user_id` and `follower_id`, with the normal index type.

Also, be sure to read on multiple-column indexing too, as it could come in handy for your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $result = array();
      header('Content-Type: application/json');

      $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE from_user = '$user_id'");
      $fcount = $query->num_rows();

      if ($fcount > 0) {

         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT A.from_user AS from_user, A.to_user AS to_user, B.* FROM follow A, story B WHERE  A.to_user = B.user_id AND A.from_user = '$user_id' GROUP BY B.user_id ORDER BY B.story_id DESC");
         $all_story = $query->result();

         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM story WHERE user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY story_id DESC");
         $twenty_post = $query->result();

         $inputArray = array_merge($twenty_post, $all_story);

         $res = array();

         foreach ($inputArray as $inputArrayItem) {

            foreach ($res as $outputArrayItem) {

               if ($inputArrayItem->story_id == $outputArrayItem->story_id) {
                  continue 2;
               }
            }
            $res[] = $inputArrayItem;
         }
      } else {
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM story WHERE user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY story_id DESC");
         $res = $query->result();
      }

      $story_image_list = array();

      foreach ($res as $key => $list) {

         $story_list['story_id'] = $list->story_id;
         $story_list['user_id'] = $list->user_id;
         $story_list['url'] = $list->url;
         $story_list['type'] = $list->type;
         $story_list['create_date'] = $list->create_date;


         $user = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $list->user_id), 1)->row();
         if (!empty($user)) {
            $story_list['username'] = $user->username;

            $url = explode(":", $user->profile_pic);
            if ($url[0] == "https" || $url[0] == "http") {
               $story_list['profile_pic'] = $user->profile_pic;
            } else {

               $story_list['profile_pic'] = base_url() . 'uploads/profile_pics/' . $user->profile_pic;
            }
         } else {
            $story_list['profile_pic'] = "";
            $story_list['username'] = "";
         }

         $story_arr = array();

         $story = $this->db->get_where('story', array('user_id' => $list->user_id))->result();
         foreach ($story as $key => $product) {

            $querycount = $this->db->query("SELECT story.url,story.type FROM story WHERE story_id = '$product->story_id'");
            $story_row = $querycount->row();

            if (!empty($story_row->url)) {

               $story_row->url = base_url() . 'uploads/story_image/' . $story_row->url;
               $story_row->type = $story_row->type;
            }
            if (!empty($story_row->url)) {
               array_push($story_arr, $story_row);
            }
            
         }

         $story_list['story_image'] = $story_arr;

         array_push($story_image_list, $story_list);
      }

      $result['status'] = "1";
      $result['msg'] = "Story Found";
      $result['post'] = $story_image_list;

      echo json_encode($result);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).